# MySQL - SELECT Most occuring value (with several same occurrences)

Tags: mysql, select

I have been looking for a way to do a MySQL select to get all the most occuring values. All the solutions i have found where with using LIMIT 1, but this doesn't help if there are more than one value that occur the same amount of times. E.g:

**customer**

| ID | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Tom |
| 3 | Bob |
| 4 | Robert |
| 5 | Tom |
| 6 | Timothy |

The Select for most occuring FirstNames should result in:

| FirstName |
| --- |
| Bob |
| Tom |

Since both occur twice.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT FirstName FROM (
  SELECT FirstName, COUNT(FirstName) as counter FROM customer
  GROUP BY FirstName
  HAVING counter = MAX(counter)
) s
```

But this doesn't seem to work, i would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be different ways for doing this

you can try

**1st**

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME 
FROM customer
GROUP BY FirstName Having count(FirstName) = (
   SELECT COUNT(FirstName) FROM customer GROUP BY FirstName ORDER BY 1 
   DESC LIMIT 1);
```

**2nd**

```
with cte as
(
  SELECT COUNT(FirstName) MaxCounter
  FROM customer 
  Group By FirstName ORDER BY  COUNT(FirstName) DESC LIMIT 1
)

SELECT c.FirstName
From customer c
Group BY FirstName
HAVING COUNT(FirstName) = (SELECT MaxCounter FROM cte)
```